# How to apply and get schengen visa after it has been rejected

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, business-travel, visa-rejections

I had posted a question here when my schengen visa was rejected once. I applied the second time and I got the visa. So I decided to post my experience and also share what I did right the second time to get my Schengen visa. I hope it helps some one who will be in my situation. If there is any other ways to share my experience kindly let me know. Cheers.